# Trigger calls class, how do you return a value back to trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger, class

How do you pass a value back to the trigger that is created from a called method?

Example:

**Trigger**

```
trigger AccountTeam on Account_Counselor__c (before insert, before update, before delete) {
....
    if(Trigger.IsInsert) {
        for (Account_Counselor__c ac : Trigger.new) {
.....
//Call Licensing Check
                        LicensingUtils.LicenseCheck(userID,accID);
}
```

**Class**

```
public class LicensingUtils {

    public static void LicenseCheck(string userID, string accID){
...Do some work
??? return boolean SendAlert = TRUE;
}
```

So after the class is complete I want the trigger to evaluate the "SendAlert" variable and take action if that field is true. Do I have to explicitly declare the variable when calling the class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have declared a return type of `void`. You can declare any return type you wish, including `Boolean`. For example:

```
public static Boolean licenseCheck(...)
{
    Boolean sendAlert = false;
    // do stuff
    return sendAlert;
}
```

See also the `Apex Developer Guide` (emphasis added):

> ## [Class Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_defining_methods.htm)
>
> To define a method, specify the following:
>
> - Optional: Modifiers, such as `public` or `protected`.
> - Required: **The data type of the value returned by the method, such as String or Integer. Use void if the method does not return a value.**
> - Required: A list of input parameters for the method, separated by commas, each preceded by its data type, and enclosed in parentheses (). If there are no parameters, use a set of empty parentheses. A method can only have 32 input parameters.
> - Required: The body of the method, enclosed in braces {}. All the code for the method, including any local variable declarations, is contained here.
>
> Use the following syntax when defining a method:
>
> ```
> [public | private | protected | global] [override] [static] ***data_type*** method_name 
> (input parameters) 
> {
> // The body of the method
> }
> ```

Comment: I have moved this conversation to **[chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53827/discussion-on-answer-by-adrian-larson-trigger-calls-class-how-do-you-return-a-v)** if you would like to further discuss.